# Process Builder - Formula Execution

Tags: formula, process-builder

I'm attempting to use process builder to execute the following formula to average a set of picklists (ran into limit with formula field). I'm getting an error that Field Mission_Aligned__c does not exist even though it does. I presume this is because process builder syntax may be different than formula field syntax. Any advice would be appreciated!

(CASE( Mission_Aligned__c,

"No elements aligned",0,

"Few elements aligned",1,

"Some elements aligned",2,

"Most elements aligned",3,

"All elements aligned",4,0)

+

CASE(Quality_Strength__c,

"Not research based",0,

"Some research based",1,

"Majority research based",2,

"Evidence informed",3,

"Evidence based",4, 0)

+

CASE( Participant_Impact__c,

"Low",0,

"Low to medium",1,

"Medium",2,

"Medium to high",3,

"High",4,0)

+

CASE( Staff_Capacity_to_Deliver__c,

"None",0,

"People in training",1,

"Minimum required staff to deliver",2,

"Minimum extra staff on hand to deliver",3,

"Numerous staff on hand to deliver",4,0)

+

CASE ( Funding_Availability__c,

"Within 5+ years",0,

"Within last 4 years",1,

"Within past 3 years",2,

"Within past 2 years",3,

"Within last year",4,0)

+

CASE ( Content_Updated__c,

"Within 5+ years",0,

"Within last 4 years",1,

"Within past 3 years",2,

"Within past 2 years",3,

"Within last year",4,0)

+

CASE ( Funding_Recency_Implementation__c,

"Within 5+ years",0,

"Within last 4 years",1,

"Within past 3 years",2,

"Within past 2 years",3,

"Within last year",4,0)

+

CASE ( Marketing_Materials_Developed_and_Utiliz__c,

"Within 5+ years",0,

"Within last 4 years",1,

"Within past 3 years",2,

"Within past 2 years",3,

"Within last year",4,0)

+

CASE ( Demand_for_languages_other_than_English__c,

"4 or more requests in last year",0,

"3 requests in last year",1,

"2 requests in last year",2,

"1 request in last year",3,

"No request in last year",4,0)

+

CASE ( Relates_to_Community_Trends_Needs_Fund__c,

"No community stakeholder trend identification",0,

"1-2 community stakeholder trend identification",1,

"3-4 community stakeholder trend identification",2,

"4-5 community stakeholder trend identification",3,

"6+ community stakeholder trend identification",4,0)

+

CASE ( Family_Interest_and_Needs__c,

"29% or less people completed the class",0,

"30%-44% people completed the class",1,

"45%-49% people completed the class",2,

"60$-84% people completed the class",3,

"85% or more people completed the class",4,0)

+

CASE ( Supports_Partnerships__c,

"0 partnerships involved",0,

"1 partnership involved",1,

"2 partnerships involved",2,

"3 partnerships involved",3,

"4+ partnerships involved",4,0))

/

(IF (ISBLANK(TEXT( Mission_Aligned__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Quality_Strength__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Participant_Impact__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Staff_Capacity_to_Deliver__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Funding_Availability__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Content_Updated__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Funding_Recency_Implementation__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Marketing_Materials_Developed_and_Utiliz__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Demand_for_languages_other_than_English__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Relates_to_Community_Trends_Needs_Fund__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Family_Interest_and_Needs__c)),0,1)

+

IF (ISBLANK(TEXT ( Supports_Partnerships__c)),0,1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix the fields like `[My_Object__c].Field_Path__c`, so your formula should instead look like:

```
(CASE([My_Object__c].Mission_Aligned__c,
    "No elements aligned",0,
    ...
```

Obviously, replace what is inside the brackets with the actual API Name of your object. Or just use the formula editor to insert the field and you will see the proper syntax for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @milad If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: Just accepted! Thanks for letting me know!